# PHP - nested output buffering

Tags: php, nested, buffering, ob-start

I have function that has :

```
ob_start();
//Include of some files
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Now in those includes is another function that uses the same code, and they seem to
conflict. Is it possible to use them like this?

Comment: How do they seem to conflict? Do you get errors?

Comment: You can't declare the same function twice, you might be able to wrap your function definition in some kind of if(!function_exists('blah')) { function blah() { ... } }

Comment: what makes you think they conflict?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try using output buffer like this :

```
ob_start();
// your includes
echo ob_get_clean();
```

Use this in all of your includes, and you will not get any errors

Comment: I had similar problem but mistakenly used ob_clean() instead ob_end_clean() - be aware of their difference!

Answer (score 11):

Output buffering should be stackable, you just need to match ob_start with ob_end_clean. See http://php.net/ob_start